# "fontFamily is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync" i'm getting this error even though i'm loading it

Tags: react-native

I get this error in React Native even though i'm using Font.loadAsync,

"fontFamily "PlusJakartaSans-SemiBold" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync."

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react'
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default function Login(){
    const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  // Load the custom font asynchronously
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFont() {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'OpenSans-Bold': require('../../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
        'PlusJakartaSans-SemiBold': require('../../assets/fonts/PlusJakartaSans-SemiBold.ttf'),
        // Add more fonts here if needed
      });
      setFontLoaded(true);
    }

    loadFont();
  }, []);
  
  // Render the component only when the font is loaded
  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

    return (
        <>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.heading}>
              <Image 
              source={require('../../assets/imgs/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />
              <Text style={styles.h1}>Logo</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.titleSection}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Log in to your Account</Text>
                <Text>Welcome back, please enter your details.</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        </>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#FFF6F0',
    },
    heading: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    logo: {
      width: 62,
      height: 44,
      marginRight: 10,
    },
    h1: {
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold',
        fontSize: 36,
        textAlign: 'center',

    },
    titleSection: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    title:{
      fontFamily: 'PlusJakartaSans-SemiBold',
      fontWeight: 600
    }
});
```

I clearly am using Font.loadAsync, Path is correct, font is supported by device and i still get this error, i have wasted alot of time trying to figure it out but i can't understand why. i tried clearing cache, realoading nothing worked. Font loads in web version but on android i get this error

Comment: npx expo install expo-font@~11.1.1, or
"expo-font": "~11.1.1" in your package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same code, have a try,
config:
`"expo": "~48.0.18", "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.71.8",`

when i try:
`yarn add expo-font`, same error
solved:
`npx expo install expo-font@~11.1.1`, or config
"expo-font": "~11.1.1" in your package.json